# Split R dataset containing a column with 3 string values into 2 datasets containing 2 string values

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

Consider me a n00b but I have searched my specific query here and I haven't found the answer yet. My problem is as follows. Consider the following simplified csv file r_split.csv which represents my dataset:

```
id,v1,v2,v3,v4,str
1,2.4,2.4,345.5,234.2,gbbc
2,4.5,2.56,7.45,34.6,ebird
3,3.4,5.6,4.45,6.3,ebird_can
```

The first row contains the header names. You can see that the column str contains 3 different string values i.e. `gbbc, ebird, ebird_can`. My objective is *to split this big dataset into 2 datasets*. The first one will only contain all the str values = `gbbc` and the second one will contain all the str values of `ebird` and `ebird_can` renamed as `allebird`.

I can split the dataset into 3 distinct datasets by using the following command:

```
splitted<-split(rsplit,rsplit$str)
```

However, I cannot figure out how to use 2 distinct values of the str column and combine them into the third. Can someone help me out please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure `str` column is not a `factor`. Use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` option within `read.csv(.)` to load all strings as characters and *not* as factors.

Second, it's fine to use `subset` during an interactive session. However, as [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset) (or [**direct link to hadley's wiki**](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Evaluation) nicely explains, it is not wise to use it within your functions.

I'd recommend direct subsetting with `[`.

```
df1 <- df[df$str == "gbbc", ]
df2 <- df[df$str != "gbbc", ]
df2$str <- "allebird"
> df1
#   id  v1  v2    v3    v4  str
# 1  1 2.4 2.4 345.5 234.2 gbbc
> df2
#   id  v1   v2   v3   v4      str
# 2  2 4.5 2.56 7.45 34.6 allebird
# 3  3 3.4 5.60 4.45  6.3 allebird
```

Alternatively, if there are just two values "gbbc" and "allebird", then you can first replace everything else except "gbbc" with "allebird" and then, as you mention, use split.

```
df3 <- df
df3$str[df3$str != "gbbc"] <- "allebird"
split(df3, df3$str)
# $allebird
#   id  v1   v2   v3   v4      str
# 2  2 4.5 2.56 7.45 34.6 allebird
# 3  3 3.4 5.60 4.45  6.3 allebird
# 
# $gbbc
#   id  v1  v2    v3    v4  str
# 1  1 2.4 2.4 345.5 234.2 gbbc
```

Comment: Thank you for the excellently explained answer ! I tried it out on my data. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `levels` function to change and merge levels of a factor.  For your case (assuming that str is already a factor with the default ordering of levels) you could do something like:

```
levels(rsplit$str) <- c('allebird','allebird','gbbc')
splitted<-split(rsplit,rsplit$str)
```

You may want to make a copy of rsplit first and modify the copy rather than the original (if you want to keep the original with the original levels).

For a more complicated example you can use tools like `grep`, `gsub`, or the gsubfn package to create the new vector of factor levels.